# Why doesn't work my jQuery selector "this" with ID anchors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a texts with tag `<a>`, if you click on them they should take you on the next anchor, with a smooth scroll.

There is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div style="width:100%;height:1500px;background-color:black;color:white;">ciao
<div>
<a class="scrolldown" style="color:white" href="#prova">ciaoooooo</a>
</div>
</div>

<div id="prova" style="width:100%;height:1500px;background-color:silver;color:white;">ciao ancora
<div>
<a class="scrolldown" style="color:white" href="#prova2">ciaoooooo</a>
</div>
</div>

<div id="prova2" style="width:100%;height:1500px;background-color:green;color:white;">basta
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".scrolldown").click(function() {
var cane = $('this').attr("href");
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(cane).offset().top},
    'slow');
});
```

**FIDDLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/mar1/yLroumv6/

Comment: `$('this')` ==> `$(this)`

Comment: `$('this')` is looking for  elements in dom  `<this>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$('this')` will select `<this>` element in the DOM. Use `$(this)`.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b9ffo7ja/)